# Select row where id in array of mysql row

Tags: mysql

So I have an database where I have a string in each row eg: `1,4,56,3,23`

I want to find every row where say 1 is in it, so this row would be found a 1 is at the start but if I have `4,1,54,32,2` it wont find it.

This is the code I'm using:

`WHERE ".$id." IN ( outcomes )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FIND_IN_SET : 
SELECT * 
FROM table 
where FIND_IN_SET(".$id.",outcomes);

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LIKE` because you have a string separated by comma.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE outcome LIKE '41,%' OR outcome LIKE '%,41,%' OR outcome LIKE '%,41';
```

The above code select users which have outcome 41 in the list.

Comment: but this would select 412 as well it thats in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INSTR function as well :

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE INSTR(".$id.",'1') > 0
```